# Format not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Code provided by @KRR

```
function insertPhoneNumbers() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("report");
 var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 3, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1)
 var sourcenotes = nrange.getValues()
 //Logger.log(sourcenotes);
 var notes = targetsheet.getRange(2, 6, sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1)
 var formatedNotes = notes.setNumberFormat(0);
 notes.setNotes(sourcenotes);
```

works and does what is supposed to but I added the

```
var formatedNotes = notes.setNumberFormat(0);
```

But the output I'm getting is the same as if I don't put the formatting instruction, which is:

> 0000000000.00000

It should be (as per Code)

> 00000000000

My first attempt was

```
var formatedNotes = notes.setNumberFormat('(000) 000-0000')
```

Didn't work either I was trying to get

> (123) 456-7890

bottom line is I can't get any format to work.

Answer (score 0):

Warp your format in quotation marks. `setNumberFormat("0")` or `setNumberFormat("(000) 000-0000")` It works fine for me like that.

Otherwise, make sure you're getting the correct sheets.

Comment: Tried 



`function insertPhoneNumbers() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("report");
 var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 3, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1)
 var sourcenotes = nrange.getValues()
 //Logger.log(sourcenotes);
 var notes = targetsheet.getRange(2, 6, sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1)
 var formatedNotes = notes.setNumberFormat("(000) 000-0000");
 notes.setNotes(sourcenotes);

}`


Didn't work either note is still being written as "1234567890.00000"

Comment: Are you sure that `targetsheet` is getting what it's supposed to get? You can also try calling `clearFormats` on the sheet, to get rid of any previous formatting before calling `setNumberFormat`.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm pasting the content as a note so I doubt there would be a previous format since there is no previous note, what really bugs me is the fact that the value I'm calling with  `getValues()` is 1234567890 but the  output `setNotes()` is giving me is 1234567890.00000